# Display names starting with L

Tags: sql

I want to select only names from a table with a code of `Ala_Cen` starting with letter `L`.

I have tried `Where [PatientList].Name Like 'L%'`, but it didn't work.

Comment: why didnt work? any error code? And what is `Ala_Cen`

Comment: it is a value in a column named HealthCentreCode

Comment: so maybe you want `Where [HealthCentreCode].Ala_Cen Like 'L%'` ??

Comment: What do you mean by code of `Ala_Cen`? Is `code` a column in the `PatientList` table?

Comment: the names are in the Name column and Ala_Cen is in the HealthCentreCode column.

Comment: This is what you need http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT pl.PatientNumber,
       pl.FName
FROM PatientList pl
WHERE pl.HealthCenterCode = 'Ala_Cen'
and pl.FName like 'L%'
```

Comment: sorry i g2g will help u guys to help me when i get back.

Answer (score 0):

Display First Names

```
SELECT FName
FROM PatientList
WHERE FName Like 'L%' AND HealthCentreCode = 'Ala_Cen'
```

Comment: By 'AS' do you mean an alias for the table or column, for example, `FName AS [First Name]`.

Comment: yeah it did it to the table name and split it into two and said it couldnt find it....... since it changed the name

Comment: Update your question to show what you currently have so you can get better assistance.  Please let us know what database system you are using.